# Problema con variable al pasarse por jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema:

Realizo una consulta con un paciente que si se encuentra en la base de datos, pero obtengo que No Existe en esta.

estoy usando jQuery uso una funcion que direcciona a otra pagina y pasa una variable 'documento' para que sea procesado en otra pagina, la funcion es la siguiente:

```js
function consultarPaciente(){
    url = "index.php?accion=consultarPaciente&documento="+$("#asignarDocumento").attr('value');
    $("#paciente").load(url);
    //alert($("#asignarDocumento").attr('value'));
}
```

La linea que tengo comentada es para observar si la variable del identificador me esta llegando, lo cual me genera en la ejecución como indefinida.

La pagina que usa el anterior codigo es el siguiente:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
        <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="encabezado">
                <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="contenido">
                <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
                <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Como se puede ver en el input donde recibo el documento del paciente se  llama asignarDocumento que es recibido en la funcion javascript antes nombrada consultarPaciente().

La funcion me direcciona a la pagina principal llamada index.php la cual recibe que accion se esta tomando y asigna la variable recibida y la manda a otra funcion para ser procesada, el codigo de la pagina index es el siguiente.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once 'Controlador/Controlador.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/GestorCita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Cita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Paciente.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Conexion.php';

    $controlador = new Controlador();

    if(isset($_GET['accion'])){

        if($_GET['accion'] == 'asignar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/asignar.php');
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/consultar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelar') {
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/cancelar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'guardarCita') {
           $controlador->agregarCita($_POST['asignarDocumento'], $_POST['medico'],
                   $_POST['fecha'], $_POST['hora'], $_POST['consultorio']); 
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarCita'){
            $controlador->consultarCitas($_POST['consultarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelarCita') {
            $controlador->cancelarCita($_POST['cancelarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarPaciente') {
            $controlador->consultarPaciente($_GET['documento']);
        }
        else{
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
        }
    }
    else{
        $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

Aqui podemos ver que instancio una clase controlador que es la que ejecuta la accion que quiero hacer en este caso es consultarPaciente, ahora veamos el codigo de la funcion de dicha clase controlador:

```
    #metodo consultar paciente
public function consultarPaciente($doc) {
    $gestorCita = new GestorCita();
    $result = $gestorCita->consultarPaciente($doc);
    require_once 'Vista/html/consultarPaciente.php'; 
}
```

Este codigo utiliza una clase gestorCita y utilizamos un metodo especifico para la busqueda del paciente, veamos la funcion en la clase gestorCita:

```
    # metodo consultar paciente
public function consultarPaciente($doc){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $conexion->abrir();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pacientes WHERE pacIdentificacion = '$doc' ";

    $conexion->consultar($sql);
    $result = $conexion->obtenerResult();
    $conexion->cerrar();

    return $result;
}
```

Este metodo devuelve un $result que serian la cantidad de filas en la consulta, volvamos a ver el codigo consultarPaciente que toma el $result y lo guarda en una variable y direcciona a la pagina consultarPacinete.php veamos la pagina:

```
 <?php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Identificacion</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Sexo</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $fila = $result->fetch_object();
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacIdentificacion ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacNombres." ".$fila->pacApellidos; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacSexo; ?>
```

```
El Paciente no se encuentra en la base de datos.<br/>
<input type="button" name="ingPaciente" value="Ingresar Paciente" id="ingPaciente" onclick="ingPaciente()">
```

Como podemos ver esta pagina  toma la variable $result del metodo que se utilizo y muestra en una tabla el paciente encontrado, en caso contrario se obtiene el mensaje que no se encuentra en la base de datos.

.El problema que detecto con el alert de la funcion en javascript en que no esta llegando la variable que direcciono.

Esta es la ejecucion del programa en el problema que tengo.

[image: Interfaz]

Muchas Gracias por su tiempo y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tu problema es que en la url la variable `documento` te la manda `undefined`?

Comment: si en el codigo comentado alert aparece indefinida y por eso creo que no realiza la consulta.

Comment: Podrias probar en vez de usar `$("#asignarDocumento").attr('value');`, usar `$("#asignarDocumento").val();`

Comment: Perfecto eso era, muchas gracias podrias explicar que diferencia habia?

Comment: Según leí en este mismo sitio, `attr(..)` solo obtiene el valor de los objetos al inicio (cuando se crea el html), y `val()` es obtener el valor de propiedad del objeto que puede cambiar muchas veces.

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu ayuda llevaba 3 dias en este problemita, pero al empezar en esto es algo dificil.

Comment: De nada amigo, me alegro haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: @Ricardo sugiero que escribas una respuesta bien documentada explicando quizá la diferencia entre `attr` y `val()` para estos casos. Lo que dices en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217457/problema-con-variable-al-pasarse-por-jquery#comment404642_217457) es explicado de forma implícita en las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100441/29967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como expliqué en mi respuesta anterior, es necesario utilizar `.val()` en lugar de `.attr()`, la razón es porque hay una diferencia en la forma en que funcionan, por ejemplo:

***.attr():*** En el caso de tu `input`, si tu asignaras un `value` definido por defecto en tu `html`, esto es lo que necesitas y funcionaria correctamente, debido a que el `.attr()` toma los atributos de tu elemento `html` que defines por defecto, por ejemplo: `id, class, value, data`, etc.

***.val():*** En el caso de val para el ejemplo de tu `input`, este funciona definiendolo directamente en el `html(value="test")` o también cuando lo escribes directamente en la pantalla de tu navegador.

Es por eso que cuando tu escribías `$("#asignarDocumento").attr('value');` te mandaba `undefined`, debido a que en tu `html` no tenias este atributo definido, si no que lo estabas escribiendo directamente en la pantalla de tu navegador.

Por lo tanto deberías de usar `.val()`, para que obtenga ese valor de tu `input` en ambos casos(directamente de tu `html` o de tu pantalla).

Como nota, el .val() tiene una funcionalidad diferente en los elementos `<select>`, debido a que el `value` de un `select` se puede usar como un identificador de un `option`, si se quisiera obtener el texto de un `select option`, sería con `.text()`.

Aquí un ejemplo donde explico la diferencia en ambos casos:

En este caso, el `.attr()` da `undefined` debido a que tu `input` no tiene un atributo `value` definido por defecto.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ValVsAttr() {
 alert($("#test").val());
 alert($("#test").attr("value"));
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="submit" onclick="ValVsAttr()" />
```

Si tu ingresas en la pantalla algún valor en tu `input` y presionas el botón enviar, el `attr()`, te dará `undefined`, mientras que le `.val()` te dará el valor.

En este otro ejemplo hemos definido por defecto un `value="test"` en el `html`, de este modo el `.attr()`, va a funcionar correctamente y el `.val()` también:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ValVsAttr() {
 alert($("#test").val());
 alert($("#test").attr("value"));
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />
<input type="submit" onclick="ValVsAttr()" />
```

Básicamente para tu ejemplo, así funcionan y así es la forma de obtener el valor dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con esto.

```
$("#asignarDocumento").val();
```

Comment: Voto en contra de tu respuesta por dos motivos: 1º. Hace 19 horas @Ricardo indicó el motivo del error, sería interesante que él escribiese una respuesta explicando el interesante error del OP, indicando que en estos casos lo correcto sería usar `val()`; 2º. La respuesta es realmente pobre, no hace otra cosa que reproducir lo que ya sugirió Ricardo en su comentario.