# jQuery: Eliminar atributo checked de un radiobotón

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, radiobutton

En mi página web sobre música tengo un sistema de votación hecho con radiobotones para que los usuarios registrados asignen a cada canción una nota de 1 a 5:

```
<span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

    <?php 

        if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"';
            echo ($i == $nota) ? " checked><i></i>" : "><i></i>";
        }

    ?>

</span>
```

Que se ve así (si por ejemplo le has dado 4 estrellas a una canción):

[image: 4 estrellas]

El sistema está controlado por un script jQuery que envía la información a través de `.ajax()` a un archivo PHP, que es el encargado de hacer la inserción en mi base de datos MySQL:

```
$(function() 
{
    /*$('input[type=radio]:checked').click(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    })*/

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
    {
        var voto = $(this).val();
        var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
        var cancion = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.row').find('.cancion').text();
        var autor = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.row').find('.autor-recopilatorio').text();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', url: 'votacion.php', data: {voto: voto, id_cancion: idCancion},
            success: function()
            {
                if(voto == 5) swal("¡Guau!", "¡Amor a primera vista!", "success");
                else if(voto == 4) swal("¡Genial!", `¡Disfruta de ${autor}!`, "success");
                else if(voto == 3) swal(":)", "Buena canción, ¿eh?", "success");
                else if(voto == 2) swal("Vaya...", `¿No te convence ${cancion}?`, "success");
                else swal("Bueno...", "No a todo el mundo le puede gustar lo mismo...", "success");
            },
            error: function()
            {
                swal("Vaya...", "Parece que tu voto no se ha podido enviar", "error");
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Posteriormente, otro archivo PHP hace una llamada a la base de datos y en bucle presenta toda la información pertinente para cada canción -vídeo de Youtube, portada del disco, datos varios del artista, etc.-, incluyendo el sistema de votación cuyo código veis al principio del mensaje.

El código PHP del sistema es tal que si el usuario ha votado previamente una canción, ésta tendrá una `$nota` en la base de datos y el radiobotón cuyo valor `$i` coincida con ella aparecerá `checked`:

```
<input type="radio" name="135" value=4 checked>
```

Bien, el sistema de votación funciona perfectamente pero a día de hoy no hay forma de borrar los votos, por lo que he empezado a modificar mi script para solucionarlo; el primer paso ha sido intentar que si el usuario hace clic en el radiobotón marcado, `checked` desaparezca:

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').click(function()
{
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
})
```

Como podéis comprobar, este trozo de código es el que aparece comentado en el cuerpo del script más arriba.

Esto en apariencia funciona; si una canción tiene `$nota` y se hace clic en el radiobotón cuyo `value` es equivalente, el atributo `checked` desaparece:

[image: 0 estrellas]

```
<input type="radio" name="135" value=4>
```

El problema es que si a continuación haces clic en otro radiobotón (en este caso, el 1, 2, 3 o 5), cambias el voto, y luego vuelves a hacer clic en el radiobotón inicial (el 4), el DOM sigue asumiendo que ése es el `checked` y vuelve a borrar el voto (aunque ahora ya no sea un 4, sino otro valor de los cinco posibles).

Obviamente, luego habría muchos otros asuntos que solucionar para que esto fuera viable, pero me llama la atención este comportamiento de `checked` que me he encontrado ya al principio. Intuyo que tiene que ver con diferencias entre `.attr()` y `.prop()`, así que a ver si me podéis echar un cable.

Comment: ¿Es posible que pongas el código en un snippet para evaluarlo?

Comment: ¿Habiendo código PHP de por medio es posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El principal problema se da por que jquery no puede detectar correctamente cuando un radio button esta desmarcado para marcarlo:

Como se puede ver en el siguiente ejemplo, el estado del radio button puede cambarse correctamente a través de los botones, pero falla al hacer click en el mismo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#radio").click(function() {  
      if($("#radio").is(':checked')) { 
          console.log("desactivar"); 
          $("#radio").prop('checked', false);     
      }else {  
          console.log("activar");  
          $("#radio").prop('checked', true); 
      }     
    });
    $("#radio_comprobar").click(function() {  
        if($("#radio").is(':checked')) {  
            console.log("Está activado");  
        } else {  
            console.log("No está activado");  
        }  
    });  
    $("#radio_activar").click(function() {  
        console.log("activar");  
        $("#radio").prop('checked', true);  
    });  
    $("#radio_desactivar").click(function() {  
        console.log("desactivar"); 
        $("#radio").prop('checked', false);  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="radio" id="radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="radio_comprobar" id="radio_comprobar" type="button" value="Comprobar" />  
<input name="radio_activar" id="radio_activar" type="button" value="Activar" />  
<input name="radio_desactivar" id="radio_desactivar" type="button" value="Desactivar" />
```

Esto ocurre por que la acción por defecto del radio button hace que se active automáticamente al hacer click, por tanto el resultado de `$("#radio").is(':checked')` es siempre `true` (y el algoritmo va siempre por verdadero, mientras que el código dentro el `else` nunca se ejecuta).

El problema puede resolverse agregando un `data-set` a los radio buttons que almacene su estado para poder compararlos luego.

En este caso agregando `data-actual` y el estado de la opción (`true` ó `false`) al radiobutton marcamos y desmarcamos la opción, para asignar el valor de data con jquery empleamos `data('set', valor)`.

```
<input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="1" data-actual=false >
```

Luego para activar el evento de cambio de estado en lugar de usar

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
```

Puedes emplear

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
```

Por otro lado tienes el problema de regresar al botón anterior al marcar una opción diferente. Para eso primero se obtiene el nombre del conjunto de radiobotones (que imagino que puedes tener varios), con:

```
var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
```

Luego debes cambiar el valor de todos los `data-actual` de la canción, para eso empleas:

```
$(`input:radio[name="${idCancion}"]`).data('actual', false);
```

Eso antes de asignar la nueva opción.

Aquí esta un ejemplo de como funcionaria el código:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function()
  {  
    var voto = $(this).val();
    var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
    var sw=$(this).data('actual');
    sw ? voto=0 : $(`input:radio[name="${idCancion}"]`).data('actual', false)
    $(this).prop('checked', !sw);
    $(this).data('actual', !sw);
    
    if(voto == 5) console.log("¡Guau!", "¡Amor a primera vista!", "success");
    else if(voto == 4) console.log("¡Genial!", `¡Disfruta del autor!`, "success");
    else if(voto == 3) console.log(":)", "Buena canción, ¿eh?", "success");
    else if(voto == 2) console.log("Vaya...", `¿No te convence la cancion?`, "success");
    else if(voto == 2) console.log("Bueno...", "No a todo el mundo le puede gustar lo mismo...", "success");
    else if(voto == 1) console.log("Bueno...", "No a todo el mundo le puede gustar lo mismo...", "success");
    else console.log("Ok...", "Tu voto se ha borrado correctamente", "success");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">
  <input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="1" data-actual=false >
  <input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="2" data-actual=false>
  <input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="3" data-actual=false>
  <input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="4" data-actual=true checked>
  <input type="radio" name="cancion_1" value="5" data-actual=false >
</span>
```

En resumen así quedaría tu código jquery:

```
  $(function() 
  {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function()
    {
      var voto = $(this).val();
      var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
      var sw=$(this).data('actual');
      sw ? voto=0 : $(`input:radio[name="${idCancion}"]`).data('actual', false)
      $(this).prop('checked', !sw);
      $(this).data('actual', !sw);
      var cancion = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.row').find('.cancion').text();
      var autor = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.row').find('.autor-recopilatorio').text();

      $.ajax(
      {
        type: 'POST', url: 'votacion.php', data: {voto: voto, id_cancion: idCancion},
        success: function()
        {
          if(voto == 5) swal("¡Guau!", "¡Amor a primera vista!", "success");
          else if(voto == 4) swal("¡Genial!", `¡Disfruta de ${autor}!`, "success");
          else if(voto == 3) swal(":)", "Buena canción, ¿eh?", "success");
          else if(voto == 2) swal("Vaya...", `¿No te convence ${cancion}?`, "success");
          else if(voto == 1) swal("Bueno...", "No a todo el mundo le puede gustar lo mismo...", "success");
          else swal("Ok...", "Tu voto se ha borrado correctamente", "success");
        },
        error: function()
        {
          swal("Vaya...", "Parece que tu voto no se ha podido enviar", "error");
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

y tu código php:

```
<span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

    <?php 

        if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
        {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"';
            echo ($i == $nota) ? " checked data-actual='true'><i></i>" : " data-actual='false'><i></i>";
        }

    ?>

</span>
```

De esa forma ya funciona como quieres.

Por ultimo respecto a tu duda sobre las diferencias entre `prop()` y `attr()`:

Ambas funciones hacen relativamente lo mismo, reemplazar `attr()` con `prop()` en el código generalmente funciona.

`attr()` devuelve un atributo HTML.

`prop()` devuelve una propiedad del elemento.

Cuando el navegador interpreta el código HTML los atributos de un elemento se transforman en propiedades.

Las propiedades son generalmente más simples de tratar que los atributos. El valor de atributo solo puede ser una cadena, mientras que una propiedad puede ser de cualquier tipo. Por ejemplo, la propiedad `checked` es un booleano, la propiedad `style` es un objeto con propiedades individuales para cada estilo, la propiedad  `size` es un número.

En resumen `attr()` es mas recomendable para obtener el valor de un atributo mientras que `prop()` es mas recomendable para asignar propiedades.

Para mas información puedes revisar:

[**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre attr y prop en jQuery?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138435/77879)

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué hay que complicarse, no es mejor determinar cuál de los radio está marcado y obtener su valor? En la pregunta tampoco queda claro el contexto, el uso que se va a dar a esto, pero supongo que es para saber la puntuación de cada canción. El OP habla también de *cuando se refresca la página*, pero no dice nada si la información se guarda y se carga de una base de datos por ejemplo, de qué forma persistiría la información (el usuario cambia de opinión, y en vez de votar 3 vota 4, de qué forma se guarda la votación final, etc ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano intente lo que menciona ya que debería ser lo mas indicado, probando con `this.checked`, `$(this).is(':checked')`, `$(this).attr('checked')` y `$(this).prop('checked')` sin tener éxito, es por eso que recurrí a usar `data-set`.

Comment: Precisamente hay que conocer el contexto para saber cómo usar `this`. Si estás en el contexto adecuado, podrás determinar cuál es el radio button que está chequeado en ese contexto. Pero la pregunta no es clara, por lo que aportar la solución más óptima resulta complicado.

Comment: Amplío la pregunta inicial con más código.

Comment: @JavierBlanco ya actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente la solución propuesta, pero también me gustaría entender por qué `checked` no funciona como yo espero (veo que has usado `.prop()` y no `.attr()`, que era una de las cuestiones acerca de las que reflexionaba en mi pregunta) para intentar desarrollar una solución propia. Me he perdido un poco con tanto atributo cambiando de `true` a `false`, la verdad.

Comment: @JavierBlanco entiendo, he investigado la razón de por que jquery no puede detectar el estado del radio correctamente, voy a agregarlo a la respuesta y voy a tratar de simplificar el código.

Comment: De hecho ya la he implementado e incluso modificado el archivo PHP con el que se comunica `.ajax()` para que borre los registros de la base de datos cuando el voto es 0, y todo funciona perfectamente, pero ayer estuve todo el día dándole vueltas al uso de `data` y me da la impresión de que estamos haciendo dos veces lo mismo... Sin embargo, operando sólo con `checked` no consigo que funcione.

Comment: Muy buena la simplificación, ¡muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: @JavierBlanco de nada, que tengas buen día.